# Error TS2724 module has no exported member, When tried to import pipe in component from package

Tags: angular

I have project structure like 3 angular projects(external,internal,common) in which common is used as a shared module and packaged using ng-package and used in other 2 projects.common will have resusable components,pipes and services which we will use internal and external projects.

The problem here is I have a pipe(documentsFilter) in common shared module. And I am using this in my internal application like the below html component tag.And I am able to pipe from the html and pipe is getting triggered and performed correctly. But When I try to use this same pipe in the corresponding component.ts file I am getting -**common"' has no exported member 'DocumentsFilterPipe'.**

**shared.Module.ts**

```
import { DocumentsFilterPipe } from '../pipes/documents-filter.pipe';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ButtonsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DocumentsFilterPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    DocumentsFilterPipe
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

I have angular component like below in which I am using pipe(documentsFilter).

```
<documents-filter [documents]="filteredDocuments() | documentsFilter: documentFilter"></documents-filter>
```

**Internal module.ts**

```
import {
  BandaroleService,
  ButtonsModule,
  SharedModule,
  DocumentsFilterComponent
} from 'common';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DocumentsFilterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ButtonsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    DirectiveModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    SharedDataService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Component file**

```
    import {
      Constants,
      SharedModule,
      Column,
      CreditOverviewSortingService
    } from 'common';
@Component({
  selector: 'documents',
  templateUrl: './documents.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./documents.component.scss'],
})
export class DocumentsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

   constructor(public constants: Constants,
              private documentService: DocumentInternalService,
              private documentsFilterPipe: DocumentsFilterPipe;
  }
```

**EDIT1:**

In the component when I import DocumentsFilterPipe like this

```
import {
  Constants,
  CreditCase,
  DocumentsFilterPipe,
} from 'common';
```

getting error like
**common"' has no exported member 'DocumentsFilterPipe'**

In the component when I import SharedModule like this

```
import {
  Constants,
  CreditCase,
  SharedModule,
} from 'common';
```

getting error like
 **error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DocumentsFilterPipe'**

Comment: In `DocumentsComponent` look at the constructor, you have `private documentsFilterPipe = DocumentsFilterPipe` instead of `private documentsFilterPipe: DocumentsFilterPipe`

Comment: On a side note, executing functions inside the template `filteredDocuments()` in addition to using [filter pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe) can have negative performance implications.

Comment: Tht was a typo error

Comment: What is `common`? The error is surrounding trying to import `DocumentsFilterPipe` from `common`.

Comment: common is also a angular project which has reusable pipes,component,services etc.. common-0.0.1.tgz is packaged using ng-package and referenced from node_modules and used in both internal and external application.

Comment: Okay, then you may need to share code of `common`, as it does not seem to export `DocumentsFilterPipe`. Can you share the exports for `common`?

Comment: but in internal application pipe is working in the html (<documents-filter [documents]="filteredDocuments() | documentsFilter: documentFilter"></documents-filter>)

Comment: sharedmodule given in the top is one of the module present in common which has this pipe.

Comment: Right but that doesn't mean there is a symbol `DocumentsFilterPipe` is specifically being exported from `common`. It being exported in `SharedModule` is not enough. If you need `DocumentsFilterPipe`, then `common` need to be updated to be able to use it directly, otherwise import `SharedModule` and use it in the template.

Comment: when I try to build the common I could see the pipe as well in the list of files in the window.

Comment: You are right I had to specifically add the pipe in the common(export pipe in public_api.ts which has all the files  to form the angular library) and then it starting taking.Thanks for the clue.

Comment: You make that an answer to possibly help others, otherwise I can

Comment: you can I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have not exported `DocumentsFilterPipe` from `public-api.ts` of the `common` library. Having `DocumentsFilterPipe` in `imports`/`exports` of `SharedModule` is not enough to be able to import it and use it directly in your projects using `common` library. Add something along the lines of the following to your `public-api.ts`:

```
export * from './path/to/documents-filter.pipe';
```

Hopefully that helps!